# EmberJS development on a machine with outdated node version

Tags: node.js, ember.js, development-environment

I have a project where I want to use the latest EmberJS to develop under. Currently, node 0.10.4 is installed on the machine I was given, which is a hard requirement for a backend system that I will need. Since the nodejs is so outdated, I cannot install the latest Ember on this machine without updating the NodeJs. My ember app has to communicate to the backend system through socket.io, is it possible to create a virtual development environment on this machine to develop Ember with the latest nodejs and also be able to easily configure the socket.io connection during development?

**I believe once Ember is compiled down to distribution files, I can easily migrate these files into the public folder of my outdated nodejs with no problem, but correct me if I'm wrong**

Any ideas on a solution that is easy to configure without asking for a new  machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this situation is to use Node Version Manager (NVM).
Just follow the install instructions located [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Then you can simply type `nvm install <desired version of node>`.

For example, when developing your backend system, first type `nvm install v0.10.4`. And when developing your Ember app, type `nvm install v6.0.0`.

(Note: to find out what versions of node are available to download, run `nvm ls-remote`).

Comment: Really easy to use, love how this automates the process and attaches the node version to the user account. Has the same effect as Yura's answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use Linux - you can do following steps:

1. create new user
2. download archive with latest node.js version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/):
3. extract archive to any folder in new user /home directory
4. then switch to created user and do `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/latest/node/bin/node" >> ~/.bashrc;`

Then you should be available to use node.js 7.*.* only for this user, but default version for other users will be 0.10.4